# Creating a multidimensional char array in C

Tags: c

I am dealing with an issue about multidimensional `char` array in C. After a time break it is hard for me for remembering the all. Try to figure out what I am doing the wrong. Platform is Ubuntu 21.10, compiler is gcc, the code is below. Any help
I would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *a1 = "hello1";
    char *a2 = "hello2";
    char b[][2] = { a1, a2 };
    printf("%s\n", b[1]);
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize arrays of characters with pointers.  You want two rows of characters so the 2 should come first, and you have to provide the second dimension too.  You could use `char b[2][7] = { “hello1”, “hello2” };`

Comment: synapsis, "Try to figure out what I am doing the wrong"  --> Enable all compiler  warnings (like -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion) and report what your compiler says.

Answer (score 5):

Because `a1` and `a2` are *pointers*, you need an array of pointers to contain them:

```
const char *b[] = { a1, a2 };  // char *b[2] = { a1, a2 } would also work
```

So what you need isn't really an array of arrays, but just a standard single one-dimensional array.

Also note that I added the `const` modifier, to make it an array of pointers to constant characters. That's because it's not allowed to modify literal strings, so all pointers to them should be made constant.

---

If you really want an array of arrays, for example so you would be able modify the strings, you first of all need to make sure that the dimensions are correct. You have two strings, so you need an array of two elements. Then you need the second "dimension" to be large enough to hold both the strings and all possible additions you might need to do.

For example:

```
char b[2][32];  // Two arrays of 32 characters each
```

But note that you can't initialize these arrays using the pointers you have, or even using other arrays. Instead you must explicitly copy the strings into the arrays:

```
strcpy(b[0], a1);
strcpy(b[1], a2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array of pointer is not a 2D array.

This defines and initializes 2D `char` array:

```
char b[][7] = {"Hello1", "Hello2"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction is

```
char *b[] ={a1,a2};
```

Corrected code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a1="hello1";
    char *a2="hello2";
    char *b[] ={a1,a2};
    printf("%s\n",b[0]);
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps. However, this has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75556978/6340496) (in greater detail).  This is a poor answer (and subject to downvotes) as it does not provide any context on the problem, nor on the proposed solution. And to be pedantic, the 'corrected code' is not explicitly correct either.

Comment: This answer would be of higher quality if it also provided some explanation, instead of only code. Code-only answers are generally not good answers.

Answer (score 0):

also a way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main() 
{
    char **matrix;
    int i = 0;

    matrix = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    matrix[0] = strdup("hello");
    matrix[1] = strdup("world");
    matrix[2] = NULL;

    while(matrix[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", matrix[i]);
        free(matrix[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's me again

```
char d1[]="hello World";//This syntax is true
char *d2="Hello World";// This is another appearance of previous line
char *a1="hello1";
char *a2="hello2";
char *c1[] ={a1,a2}; //This line is also working
char **c2={a1,a2};   /*Right part of the assignment operator is data.
Can we assing data to c2 like this, I am a little confused. Is that correct*/
```

Thanks for assist